# Can anyone help me find the infimum of the sequence $A=\{1/(1+x^2) : x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone help me with this problem? I'am sorry, I don't know how to write math formulas in stack exchange.

I'am trying to prove that infA=0.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Well, you can learn how to write math in https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several definitions for the infimum of a set of real numbers. Depending on what you are expected to know, some will be easier to manipulate in different circumstances, but I will go with the most basic one: the infimum of $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$.

So you have two points to prove:

- 0 is a lower bound of your set, *i.e.* $\forall a \in A, 0 \leq a$.
  This should be easy to prove.
- If you take any real number $\varepsilon > 0$, then it is not a lower bound of $A$. Said differently, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, you can find an element $a \in A$ smaller than $\varepsilon$. This amounts to solving an easy inequality.

Another method, using the sequential characterization of the infimum, would be to find a sequence $(a_n) \in A^{\mathbb N}$ converging to $0$. This is a quicker, easier way to prove that $\inf A = 0$, but it is a bit more advanced (*i.e.* the fact that this gives an equivalent defintion of the infimum is not completely immediate).

Comment: So, in the second part of the prove, if I solve the inequality a=1/1+x^2<ϵ for x, I find a value of x∈Q in function of ϵ such that ϵ>a? Proving that ϵ is not a lower bound of A

Comment: Exactly ! Hence, no positive real number can be a lower bound of $A$, so $0$ will indeed be the greatest lower bound.

Comment: Numbra, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Clearly $\forall x \in A, x \ge 0$.

Given a small positive number $\epsilon>0$, can you find $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that

$$\frac1{1+x^2} < \epsilon$$

Try to convince yourself that you can do so by solving the inequality for $x$.